# Video not playing after partial upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, partial-upgrade

![in the middle of my upgraded from 11.10 - 12.04 it was interupted with an electrical outage, when the power is back and as i resume my upgrade i was asked for "partial install". and after the process is complete. all cleaned up.

i got these error prompt. "/usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py" and "The application Unity 2D Shell has closed unexpectedly"  and i can't play any videos from any player as well. it will just display a black screen and only the audio will play. help.][1]

Comment: You say you got "these error prompts".  What are the errors specifically?

Answer (score 0):

Your graphics drivers cannot be found, in this case the Intel Graphics that are a part of every Intel CPU. Because these drivers cannot be found, you are going to have a tough time getting a GUI on the computer, and even when you do it's gong to be glitchy and unreliable. Your best bet in this case is to boot to the Ubuntu Live CD and transfer any files you want to keep to an external hard drive or flash drive, then reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: oh..i am using a laptop..
toshiba L500
Memory: 2.8 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3 CPU M 330 @ 2.13GHz × 4
Graphics: Intel® Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2 
OS type: 32-bit
Dual Boot Win7

Comment: YEp, laptop or desktop that will not make a difference. Your graphics drivers are gone and your best bet is to reinstall.

Comment: @James Henstridge If only i can show you the screen capture of error prompt..or if only i know how to post the error list..

Comment: @JamesHenstridge "Apport has detected a possible GPU hang.  Did your system recently lock up and/or require a hard reboot?"